# Function that will receive 2 numbers as input and it should return the multiplication of these 2 numbers

Tags: python, input, int, multiplication

Im playing Checkio website to learn more about python but I dont seem to be able to solve the very first problem.This is it:

Write a function that will receive 2 numbers as input and it should return the multiplication of these 2 numbers.

**Input**: Two arguments. Both are int

**Output:** Int.

Now, they give me this code:

```
def mult_two(a, b):
  # your code here
  return mult_two


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Example:")
    print(mult_two(3, 2))

    # These "asserts" are used for self-checking and not for an auto-testing
    assert mult_two(3, 2) == 6
    assert mult_two(1, 0) == 0
    print("Coding complete? Click 'Check' to earn cool rewards!")
```

in the #Your code here  part, i need to add the answer, but I have no clue. Please help.

Comment: As a starting point, think about how you would write a program that multiplies two numbers, _without_ a function. Then take that code and put it in your function.

Comment: I tried putting this: def mult_two(a, b):
                                   mult_two= 3*2
                                   return mult_two

Comment: Edit the question with your attempt. Don't put it in the comments

Comment: But it gave me this error: Example:
                                        6
                                         AssertionError: 
                                        <module>, 12

Comment: Hint: Generally, the parameters of a function should be used inside the body of that function. In other words, `a` and `b` should appear somewhere in your return statement.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem seems pretty basic. Here is a possible way of writing you function **mult_two**:

```
def mult_two(a, b):
   """ Return the product of the two arguments."""
    return a * b
```